# How to derive the long range behavior of XY model?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, statistical-mechanics, correlation-functions, critical-phenomena

In a lecture note (Lec 23) by Sachdev (https://canvas.harvard.edu/courses/76589/files/folder/Lectures?), he considers a model
$$Z=\int D\theta(x)\,exp(-\frac{K}{2\pi}\int d^{2}x\,(\nabla_x\theta)^2),$$ and defines an order parameter $\psi(x)=e^{i\theta(x)}$, then calculate the correlation function
$$<\psi(x)\psi^{*}(0)>=exp(-\frac{\pi}{K}\int^{\Lambda}\frac{d^{2}k}{4\pi^2}\frac{1-cos(k\cdot x)}{k^2}),$$ and when $|x|\to\infty$,above equation approximates to
$$<\psi(x)\psi^{*}(0)>\approx exp(-\frac{1}{2K}ln(\Lambda|x|))=1/(\Lambda|x|)^{1/(2K)}.$$

**1. How to write down such long range behavior**, and it seems that this power law decay behavior is very strange, since the power depends on the tunable interaction parameter K.

**2. Is it possible to write down the scaling dimension of $\psi(x)$?** Then it is easy to write down the long range behavior, say, we know that if $[\phi]=\frac{d-2+\eta}{2}$, then $$<\phi(x)\phi(0)>\sim 1/r^{d-2+\eta}.$$

Comment: A part of solution for question 1: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4580141/how-to-do-the-integral-int-fracddk2-pid-frac1-cos-veck-cdot